# Change File dynamically using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to change my file dynamically according to the screen resolution mean I have three files

1. index.php
2. main.js
3. testA.php
4. testB.php

index.php will dynamically call the file testA and testB

I mean if the size of the screen resolution is equal to the desktop the php in index.php will include the testA.php and elseif  the size of the screen resolution is equal to the mobile the it will include testB.php. How can I get it to work using ajax and javascript

Comment: Have you logged in to the wp-admin?

Comment: I am using wordpress on localhost

Comment: Sure, that's nice, but have you logged in to the wp-admin? You can't create posts unless you're logged in, regardless where the post data comes from. If you could, it would be the biggest security whole ever.

Comment: I give u a video link and please see it https://youtu.be/rGObWtjxGBc?t=26m30s

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure how you expect us to be able to help you if you won't even answer a simple, yet very relevant, "yes" or "no" question.

Answer (score 1):

> You are getting 403 Error Which is due to insufficient permission. You don't really have issue with "**Json stringify function error**"

Please check that you have correct permissions to create a post with the user you are logged in with.

For ex. if you are subscriber, you can't create a post. You need to be an administrator or an editor role.

Comment: I have logged in as Administrator